# Configuring Environment-Specific Redirect URLs in Next.js with Supabase Auth

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase

I am developing a Next.js application with Supabase authentication. In my Supabase settings, the 'Site URL' is set to `https://some-production-url.com` for the production environment. However, for local development, I need the redirect URL to point to localhost:3000 instead. Currently, even during local development, the application redirects to the production URL. How can I configure different redirect URLs for the production and local environments?

**Current Configuration:**

- Supabase 'Site URL' is set to `https://some-production-url.com`.
- Authentication setup in my Next.js project:

```js
async function signInWithSocialProvider(provider: any) {
    "use server"

    const origin = headers().get("origin")
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const supabase = createClient(cookieStore)

    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: provider,
      options: {
        redirectTo: `${origin}/auth/callback`,
      },
    })

    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return redirect("/login?message=Could not authenticate user")
    }

    redirect(data.url)
  }
```

Auth Callback:

```js
import { createClient } from "@/lib/supabase/server"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const code = requestUrl.searchParams.get("code")

  if (code) {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const supabase = createClient(cookieStore)
    await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code)
  }

  return NextResponse.redirect(requestUrl.origin)
}
```

**Expected Behavior:**
When running the application locally, I expect Supabase authentication to redirect to localhost:3000 after successful authentication. In the production environment, it should redirect to `https://some-production-url.com`.

**Actual Behavior:**
The application redirects to the production URL (`https://production_url.com.`) after authentication, regardless of the environment (local or production).

**Attempted Solutions:**
I added `localhost:3000` to the Redirect URLs section in Supabase alongside the Site URL. However, data.url in the authentication function always points towards the Site URL. Without using data.url, I am unable to make the authentication work.

**Questions:**

- How can I set up my Next.js application with Supabase auth to handle different redirect URLs for production and local development environments?
- Is there a way to dynamically set the redirect URL based on the environment the app is running in, such as using environment variables or some other method?

Any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address this issue add `http://localhost:3000/**` to your redirect URLs in Supabase under **URL configuration**. This is the recommended way by [Supase docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/concepts/redirect-urls).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an environment variable in combination with `NODE_ENV` to check wether you are currently on supabase or not. Here is an updated code snippet based on your example:

```js
// TODO: you probably should use a type here
function getRedirectUrl(data: any): string {
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV!) {
    case "production":
      return data.url;
    default:
      // change the existing redirect url to localhost
      // for development purposes
      const url = new URL(data.url);
      url.searchParams.set("redirect_to", process.env.SUPABASE_URL!);
      return url.toString();
  }
}

// TODO: you probably should use a type here
async function signInWithSocialProvider(provider: any) {
  "use server";

  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const origin = headers().get("origin");
  const supabase = createClient(cookieStore);

  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: provider,
    options: { redirectTo: `${origin}/auth/callback` },
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return redirect("/login?message=Could not authenticate user");
  }

  redirect(getRedirectUrl(data));
}
```

Now you can create the `.env.development.local` and `.env.test.local` files inside your project root to define different values for development and testing:

```
SUPABASE_URL="http://localhost:3000/auth/callback"
```

Comment: I initially thought about a similar way of controling it, but it does seem to need a bit more to work. Here is an example if I console.log(data.url)

'https://mdfjkhckjsdflksl.supabase.co/auth/v1/authorize?provider=google&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fcallback&code_challenge=Oredsfsdfdf4343rfd34lGHGsdfsds7sdddss-vfzliRA&code_challenge_method=s256'

Comment: @MathiasRiisSorensen I have made some changes to my answer, rather than simple returning a different url, we manipulate the existing url with your environment variable.

Comment: I tried implementing that but it still redirect me to my production URL. Not usre if it has something to do with options: { redirectTo: `${origin}/auth/callback` },

Comment: @MathiasRiisSorensen That is a very real possibility, is this endpoint getting called by you or supabase? Because if it is the latter this could explain it.

Comment: I have added the auth callback in the original description now, so you can see what is going on. :)

Comment: So I figured out that I should add the production url to redirect urls and site url should should have localhost:3000 configured, then the code would figure it out itself. 

Supabase really needs to update the documentation as fast as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I added `http://localhost:3000`to Site URL instead of using my production URL, then I added my production URL to Redirect URLs.

It's still a bit confusion to me, why I had to do the swap, and no documentation is mentioning it.